# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, programming, android-studio

Can anyone help me please?
I'm beginner.

LOGS :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ghaas.androideatit, PID: 5835
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ghaas.androideatit/com.example.ghaas.androideatit.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.ghaas.androideatit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.ghaas.androideatit;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    TextView txtSlogan;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

        txtSlogan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Nabila.ttf");
        txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

How can i fix this issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Test replacing this:

```
btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
```

for:

```
btnSignIn = (FButton)findById(R.id.btnSignIn);
btnSignUp = (FButton)findById(R.id.btnSignUp);
```

Comment: Not work, but I replace <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton/> from main_activity.xml to <Button/>, then work ,, Do you think the issue from info.hoang8f.widget.FButton Library?  Thank you for help :)